# User story for web page

Tags: scrum, user-stories

I'm Creating a web site for my girlfriend and I'm using it to get my head around user story writing / scrum and vso.  I'm trying to write a user story for the homepage which will be quite simple but graphical.  It's my understanding that I should write a user story in the first person and it's a quick description about what that user wants / expects.  The acceptance criteria is where the specifics go.  With this in mind how would you go about writing a user story for a home page. So far I have the following.

> ### User Story
>
> As the site owner I would like a homepage that shows my completed work in as a set of full size images that change periodically so that the visitor instantly sees what services I offer.
>
> ### Acceptance Criteria
>
> Can I have have 4 full size background images that change periodically?
>   Can the background images resize depending on which device they are viewed on? Can the background images load in a timely manner?

Would you say that this user story and the acceptance criteria are adequate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user story is in the voice of the *end user*, not the person delivering the service.

So in your case, it might be something like:

> As a visitor to the site I would like to instantly see what services are offered so that I can easily select a service

Notice that it doesn't say anything about images. The images and their size are *implementation details*. The user story is about what they user wants, not how they will get it.

The acceptance criteria look fine. Be carefull of statements like:

> Can the background images load in a timely manner?

Generally you would expect an acceptance criteria to define what 'a timely manner' means.

Something like:

> Can the background images load in under 3 seconds when running on our production server under normal load.